# How to implement proguard in ionic3 applications

Tags: ionic-framework, proguard, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugin-proguard

I am working on Android hybrid application using ionic3 framework,
is it possible to do ProGuard for hybrid ionic applications then please suggest me proper way.

Comment: use cordova-plugin-proguard

Answer (score 0):

For ionic, you can use almost any cordova plugin available since ionic Ionic uses cordova for building. And Cordova have plugin for using proguard.

Try using this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-proguard

To install cordova plugin in ionic app.
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-proguard

Comment: I have followed the above plugin, but that is not at all working, no size change in apk & not obfuscated

Comment: What are the general rules for android app in ionic 3 proguard please help ?